# Rails: displaying a value dynamically calculated in my form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my new.html.erb, I have the following:

```
<%= hidden_field :shipping_charges %>
<%= label_tag :rush_shipment, "Rush My Shipment" %>>
<%= check_box_tag :rush_shipment, :checked => false, :onclick => "add_rush_shipment_charges()" %>

    <p>My Shipping charges: <span id="shipping_charges"></span>
```

In my javascript file, I have the following:

```
function add_rush_shipment_charges()
{
    document.getElementById('shipping_charges').value = 25;
}
```

When I click on the checkbox, I'm supposed to see 25 appear after Shipping charges, but nothing is happening. Any ideas.

## EDIT:

Note that I edited the question to reflect the info I got from answer #1, but I am still not seeing anything.

Comment: "I'm supposed to see 25 appear after shipping charges". You're changing the value of `#payment_value`, not `#shipping_charges`.

Comment: Typo. I edited the question to reflect that. Even if I do something like: <%= hidden_field :shipping_charges, :value => 50 %> I'm still not seeing anything after "Shipping Charges".

Comment: make sure you're loading the javascript file. I would do it with something like `alert("yup, loaded");`

Comment: It does not look like the javascript file is loading. I have the function in a file with the same name as the model, which is supposed to load it. There are however 2 files with the same name, but different extensions, one with a .js.cofeee extension and the other with a .js extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkbox tag is incorrect:

```
<%= check_box_tag :rush_shipment, :checked => false, :onclick => "add_rush_shipment_charges()" %>
```

Should be:

```
<%= check_box_tag :rush_shipment, "yes", false, :onclick => "add_rush_shipment_charges()" %>
```

Until you fix that, the JavaScript method will not be called on clicks.

The JavaScript method is not correct either, as you can not set standard DOM, such as a span, using `.value`, you must use innerHTML (or better, use jQuery's `.html()` method for better cross-browser support):

```
function add_rush_shipment_charges()
{
    document.getElementById('shipping_charges').innerHTML = '25';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Where you want to show the shipping charges? Lets assume your view is like:
<%= hidden_field :shipping_charges %>
<%= label_tag :rush_shipment, "Rush My Shipment" %>>
<%= check_box_tag :rush_shipment, :checked => false, :onclick => "add_rush_shipment_charges()" %>
<h3> You shipping charges are: <span id="total_shipping"></span</h1>
```

Now, after calculating the total costs of shipping, you just update the span

```
function calculate_total_costs(){
  //cost calculation logics
  document.getElementById('total_shipping').value = TOTAL_COSTS
}
```

Now, call the function `calculate_total_costs()` when you want!

Comment: This is not working. I am not sure where total_shipping comes from, but I'll assume that you meant to add a statement like this to new.html.erb: <%= hidden_field :total_shipping_charges %> and then change the :onclick action to "calculate_total_cost". This is not showing. Even if I assign a value to total_shipping, it is not showing (I fixed the typo you have in the code you posted - missing > from </span>

Comment: please check the markup i've given! I've added an span with id `total_shipping`

Comment: The problem with your original code is that you've got two elements with the same DOM id, the hidden input and the span. HungryCoder fixed that by changing the value of the id in the span.

Comment: Tom L: That was the piece of info I was missing. I think I also have another issue: I don't think the Javascript function is loading. I am under the impression that if I put the functions in a file with the same name as the controller (in the assets/javascripts folder), then they are loaded. Would Rails be confused if I have two files, one with the extension .js.coffee and the other with the extension .js?